# Reading sqlalchemy error returns invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid unicode character

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm using sqlalchemy to read a query. My code is the next:

```
def conection(file_name, server, database, uid, pwd):
    cnxn = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}".format(urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER=SQL SERVER;\
                            SERVER={0};PORT=1433;DATABASE={1};UID={2};PWD={3};TDS_Version=8.0;".format(server, database, uid, pwd))))
    pd.read_sql(query, cnxn, chunksize=100)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Connect to the ODBC and extract the tables')
parser.add_argument('-table', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()

sql_path = os.path.join('..', 'SQL')
filename_base = args.table
sql_filename = os.path.join(sql_path, filename_base)

with open(os.path.join('..', '..', '..', 'configuration', 'connnection.json')) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

query = obtain_query(sql_filename)
cnxn = conection(filename_base,
                        data[filename_base]['server'],
                        data[filename_base]['database'],
                        data[filename_base]['uid'],
                        data[filename_base]['pwd'])
```

However I receive the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'L'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'.C.u.s.t.o.m.e.r.C.o.d.e.' is an invalid name because it contains a NULL character or an invalid unicode character. (1055)")
```

Here is an example of my table:

[image]

As you can see, I don't have null values or invalid characters since it's just numbers as text. I already checked and there is no null values or unicode characters.

The query I'm using is just a basic select:

```
SELECT
     [Customer]
    ,[Account]
    ,[Country]
    ,[Metric1]
    ,[Metric2]
    ,[Metric3]
    ,[Metric4]
FROM 
    [Table1]
```

Comment: Can you show us the query you use?

Comment: @Owen I just added it to the description.

Comment: OK, can you show the code you use to execute that query? I'm asking because the error is in the query itself. It looks like a column name is malformed (or possibly the table name).

Comment: @Owen Sure! I just updated the description with it

Comment: @Owen One question... the name of the table has an underscore _ do you think this may be the problem?

Comment: The error is showing something that called CustomerCode (a column, perhaps) is being sent as C.u.s.t.o.m.e.r.C.o.d.e Print your query and have a look at it.

Comment: @Owen the query is throwing garbage, I think there's an error while reading it. Thanks so much! Know I know what is causing the error.

Comment: You've constructed the `def conection(...)` function poorly. Remove `pd.read_sql(query, cnxn, chunksize=100)` and replace with `return cnxn` then place `pd.read_sql(query, cnxn, chunksize=100)` at the end of your code

Answer (score 0):

in your query try, for the columns which give you an error try to use

```
REPLACE(name_col,char(13)+char(10), ' ') as name_col
```

something like this...

```
SELECT
      REPLACE(Customer,char(13)+char(10), ' ') as Customer
     ,REPLACE(Account,char(13)+char(10), ' ') as Account
      .....
FROM 
    [Table1]
```